# Hide content title when notification is expanded

Tags: android, push-notification, custom-view

Hi I want to design my notification in my android app such that when notification is expanded the content title portion should hide just like Inshorts.

Right now my code is such :

```
     NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.push)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setSubText(messageDec)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher_st))
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    //CUSTOM NOTI
    if(!imageUrl.isEmpty()) {
        NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle s = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
        s.bigPicture(image);
        notificationBuilder.setStyle(s);
    }

NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
   notificationManager.notify(requestCode, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Can anybody please suggest a solution.